# change mapbox fill-extrusion-height by using setPaintProperty

Tags: javascript, 3d, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

borrow a example on fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/tyf76u0d/4/

```
 $('button').click(function() {

    map.setPaintProperty('3d-buildings', 'fill-extrusion-height', Math.random()*250 + 50);

})
```

this code change the all height of the buildings.

how can i set the buildings in different height by using 'setPaintProperty' or in others way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use a data-driven styling approach here:

1. Change `fill-extrusion-height` to use an expression which uses the value of a property of the underlying feature (building):

   ```
   map.setPaintProperty('3d-buildings', 'fill-extrusion-height', ['get', 'building-height'])
   ```

   Docs: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-get
2. Update the underlying data, mapbox will re-render automatically pulling the new height from the updated property:

   ```
   map
   .getSource('your-source-id')
   .setData(/* the updated geojson data */)
   ```

   Docs: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api#geojsonsource#setdata

Comment: thx! i use the second way. but ‘setData’ just jump to the end status. sad